# subtracting two integers which have different indexes but the same value

Tags: javascript

The given function should accept any array with any number of integers.

After it should subtract each two integers from each other beside integers which the same index.

```
var ArrayFirst = [4, 34, 6, 1,5];
var ArraySecond = [4,34,6,1,4];

function Find(Arg) {
var ResultArray;
var SecondArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Arg.length; i++) {
    var FirsArray;

    for (var j = 0; j < Arg.length; j++) {

        if (Arg.indexOf(Arg[i]) != Arg.indexOf(Arg[j])) {
            console.log(Arg.indexOf(Arg[i]) + 'AND' + Arg.indexOf(Arg[j]));
            FirstArray = Arg[i] - Arg[j];
            console.log(FirstArray);
            if (FirstArray >= 0) {

                SecondArray.push(FirstArray);
            }
        }
    }
    //console.log(SecondArray);
}
ResultArray = Math.min.apply(this, SecondArray);
console.log(ResultArray);
return ResultArray;
}
```

So After debuging I found that function Find works with ArrayFirst but not with ArraySecond

Question : Why function is not working when Array has two integers with the same value ?

UPDATED

Sorry guys that I haven't putted more details

Task: Create a function which as result will give the sum of subtracting two integers from an array, the sum cannot be subtraction of two integers which have the same index, the sum cannot be bellow 0, the sum closest to the 0 will be the proper result.

Example: [4,6,3,56,4]
4-6,4-3...4-4, then 6-4,6-3...6-4 then etc 
So result will be 0 because 4-4 sum is 0

Some Hints

Firstly i thought maybe it is something to do with operation on array but then i used apply and call on arguments

```
  if (Array.prototype.indexOf.apply(arguments[0],[arguments[0][i]]) !== Array.prototype.indexOf.apply(arguments[0],[arguments[0][j]])) {

            FirstArray = arguments[0][i] - arguments[0][j];
            if (FirstArray >= 0) {

                SecondArray.push(FirstArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

But is still not working, I tried the solution with to arguments, doesn't work either.

Comment: Try using `.map()` it was designed for this purpose

Comment: what are expected results? Not really understanding description. Also why do you define FirstArray as an array then change it's type to an integer?

Comment: When two integers in the array have the same value, subtracting them will result in `0` and that will get pushed into `SecondArray`. The smallest value you've allowed in that array is `0`, so `ResultArray` will ultimately be `0`.
Are you expecting a different value?

Comment: By the way, don't use the word `Array` in variable names. It's very confusing, especially since you've got two arrays in this code that aren't even arrays at all.
Also, `FirsArray` is a typo (and not an array because it's quickly replaced with a Number value).

Comment: HankScorpio You are right it should be 0 but it is not, I mean when array has two integers with the same value , function is not wokring and i don't know why, could you write function that works as I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost avoid using **Array** as a variable name because for the most browser it will lead to unexpected behavior.

I think also you need to pass the two arrays in your function as parameters in order compare them.

And you don't need to find the index of element with index *i*, the *i* itself is an index.

```
Array.indexOf(Array[i]) === i
```

Here is an example of what you might need:

```
// it is important for the "array" value to start with lower case symbow, because JavaScript is case sensitive language and it already has object called "Array"
var array = [4, 6, 3, 56, 4];

function find(array)
{
    // because we are surching for the minimum, the variable that will hold it needs to have the largest possible variable at the begining
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j=0 ; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                var sum = array[i] - array[j];
                // if it sum is greater than zero and it is the smallest sum so far we will save it in "min"
                if (sum >= 0 && min > sum)
                {
                    min = sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // retun the smallest sum we've encountered
    return min;
}


console.log(find(array));
```

Comment: Good hint i changed it already but i doesn't make still enough for explanation, I made some updates on question.

Comment: I overcomplicated everything,  your solution is fine for me, but my curiosity is not satisfied. Why this if conditional is not working when i compare array.indexOf(array[i]) ?? Actually it works but only then when the array has not two integers which have the same value.

Comment: Your code is working fine, the only error comes again from the indexOf in the case of *ArraySecond* ArraySecond.indexOf(ArraySecond[4]) will return 0 instead of 4, because *indexOf* aways return the first index with that value.